# Find the nearest geo positions

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, geometry, computational-geometry

I am looking for a way to get the nearly geo positions from one geo position. I can calculate the difference from two position, but I need to find all geo positions from a point with a radius of 10-20 miles. I find a similaire on flickr:

http://m.flickr.com/#/nearby/

Anybody an idear how it works? They must convert a latitude and longitude to a unique value and must find all entries nearly this position or something else.

Thanks for help!

Answer (score 1):

You might use [Voronoi Diagrams](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voronoi_diagram), but probably pre-sorting your data by each coordinate (separately) and then finding an intersection of point sets which lay nearby for each of coordinates would solve your problem easier.

> A [point location](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Point_location) data structure can be built on top of the Voronoi diagram in order to answer nearest [neighbor queries](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nearest_neighbor), where one wants to find the object that is closest to a given query point. Nearest neighbor queries have numerous applications.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a kd-Tree. Some time ago I tried this one and it worked quite well:

https://github.com/jmhodges/kdtree2

Answer (score 0):

Use a (point-)quad tree, or k-d tree, or if the number of points is not high, you even could use a brute force search.
Do not use voronoi diagrams. They are one of the most complex algos to implement.